# test with missing standard errors

Tags: stata

How can I conduct a hypothesis test in Stata when my predictor perfectly predicts my dependent variable?

I would like to run the same regression over many subsets of my data. For each regression, I would then like to test the hypothesis that beta_1 = 1/2. However, for some subsets, I have perfect collinearity, and Stata is not able to calculate standard errors.

For example, in the below case,

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen value = 2*foreign*(price<6165)
gen value2 = 2*foreign*(price>6165)
gen id = 1 + (price<6165)
```

I get the output

```
. reg foreign value value2 weight length, noconstant 

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  4,    70) =       .
       Model |          22     4         5.5           Prob > F      =       .
    Residual |           0    70           0           R-squared     =  1.0000
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  1.0000
       Total |          22    74  .297297297           Root MSE      =       0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       value |         .5          .        .       .            .           .
      value2 |         .5          .        .       .            .           .
      weight |   3.54e-19          .        .       .            .           .
      length |  -6.31e-18          .        .       .            .           .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
. test value = .5

 ( 1)  value = .5

       F(  1,    70) =       .
            Prob > F =         .
```

In the actual data, there is usually more variation. So I can identify the cases where the predictor does a very good job of predicting the DV--but I miss those cases where prediction is perfect. Is there a way to conduct a hypothesis test that catches these cases?

EDIT:
The end goal would be to classify observations within subsets based on the hypothesis test. If I cannot reject the hypothesis at the 95% confidence level, I classify the observation as type 1. Below, *both* groups would be classified as type 1, though I only want the second group.

```
gen type = .
for values 1/2 {
    quietly: reg foreign value value2 weight length if id = `i', noconstant 
    test value = .5
    replace type = 1 if r(p)>.05 
}
```

Comment: What would your hypothesis test return as a result in these cases? And what is your end goal? A message in the results window, a figure to be exported, or ...? Knowing a bit more would probably help someone answer helpfully.

Comment: This appears off-topic for SO: See "What topics can I ask about here?": http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It would seem that `r(p) = .` would satisfy your condition of `r(p) > 0.05` and therefore `type` would be set `= 1`. What about this isn't working the way you want it to?

Comment: Thank you @BrendanCox, you are right, my simplified version was too simplified. I have revised it, to show that when the predictor provides perfect information or no information, the test provides the same results.

Comment: Unfortunately, your `forvalues {...}` syntax is off, and it's still not very clear what you're trying to do here. Based on your current syntax, `r(p) > 0.05` will be satisfied for _all observations_ if _any_ loop has a p-value > 0.05, including missing.

Comment: Yes, exactly! That is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this out of the box that I'm aware of. Of course you could program it yourself to get an approximation of the p-value in these cases. The standard error is missing here because the relationship between x and y is perfectly collinear. There is no noise in the model, nothing deviates.

Interestingly enough though, the standard error of the estimate is useless in this case anyway. `test` performs a Wald test for `beta_i = exp` against `beta_i  != exp`, not a t-test.

The Wald test uses the variance-covariance matrix from the regression. To see this yourself, refer to the Methods and formulas section [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rtest.pdf) and run the following code:

(also, if you remove the `-1` from `gen mpg2 =` and run, you will see the issue)

```
sysuse auto, clear

gen mpg2 = mpg * 2.5 - 1
qui reg mpg2 mpg, nocons

* collect matrices to calculate Wald statistic
mat b = e(b)    // Vector of Coefficients
mat V = e(V)    // Var-Cov matrix
mat R = (1)     // for use in Rb-r. This does not == [0,1] because of 
                   the use of the noconstant option in regress
mat r = (2.5)   // Value you want to test for equality

mat W = (R*b-r)'*inv(R*V*R')*(R*b-r)
    // This is where it breaks for you, because with perfect collinearity, V == 0

reg mpg2 mpg, nocons

test mpg = 2.5
sca F = r(F)

sca list F
mat list W
```

Now, as @Brendan Cox suggested, you might be able to simply use the missing value returned in `r(p)` to condition your `replace` command. Depending on exactly how you are using it. A word of caution on this, however, is that when the relationship between some x and y is such that `y = 2x`, and you want to `test x = 5` *vs* `test x = 2`, you will want to be very careful about the interpretation of missing p-values - In both cases they are classified as `type == 1`, where the `test x = 2` command should not result in that outcome.

Another work-around would be to simply set p = 0 in these cases, since the variance estimate will asymptotically approach 0 as the linear relationship becomes near perfect, and thus the Wald statistic will approach infinity (driving p down, all else equal).

A final yet more complicated work-around in this case could be to calculate the F-statistic manually using the formula in the manual, and setting V to some arbitrary, yet infinitesimally small number. I've included code to do this below, but it is quite a bit more involved than simply issuing the `test` command, and in truth only an approximation of the actual p-value from the F distribution.

```
clear * 
sysuse auto

gen i = ceil(_n/5)
qui sum i

gen mpg2 = mpg * 2 if i <= 5          // Get different estimation results
replace mpg2 = mpg * 10 if i > 5      // over different subsets of data

gen type = .

local N = _N                          // use for d.f. calculation later
local iMax = r(max)                   // use to iterate loop

forvalues i = 1/`iMax' {
    qui reg mpg2 mpg if i == `i', nocons
    mat b`i' = e(b)                   // collect returned results for Wald stat
    mat V`i' = e(V)
    sca cov`i' = V`i'[1,1]

    mat R`i' = (1)
    mat r`i' = (2)                    // Value you wish to test against

    if (cov`i' == 0) {                // set V to be very small if Variance = 0 & calculate Wald
        mat V`i' = 1.0e-14
    }
mat W`i' = (R`i'*b`i'-r`i')'*inv(R`i'*V`i'*R`i'')*(R`i'*b`i'-r`i')

    sca W`i' = W`i'[1,1]              // collect Wald statistic into scalar
    sca p`i' = Ftail(1,`N'-2, W`i')   // pull p-value from F dist
    if p`i' > .05 {
        replace type = 1 if i == `i'  
    }
}
```

Also note that this workaround will become slightly more involved if you want to test multiple coefficients.

I'm not sure if I advise these approaches without issuing a word of caution considering you are in a very real sense "making up" variance estimates, but without a variance estimate you wont be able to test the coefficients at all.

Comment: thanks, this is a really helpful and thoughtful response